# Sci-fi short story about aboriginal man put into a dome with a sophisticated woman, so that they could be studied by psychologists

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read the story around 1984, part of a collection. A man who is rough, primitive in behavior, is captured, and placed within a "habitation" dome, along with a much more sophisticated woman also captured, so that their behavior may be studied by psychologists. She finds his behavior abhorrent, repugnant, but eventually finds comfort in his simplicity, and bonds with him.

Comment: Familiar, do you remember them producing a baby at some point?

Comment: Are they captured by humans or aliens? What is the man's behavior that the sophisticated woman finds abhorrent? Does he eat with his fingers, scratch himself, use substandard grammar, or what?

Comment: He doesn’t speak. He is industrious, doing the needed daily tasks to live. Cave-man like. She is a bit hoity-toiryllty, far out of her prim and propper confort zone

Comment: I can’t recall them producing a baby; it seems the story ended before then. But a longer story would certainly have led to that. Perhaps it did and I am not recalling. Bur the last scene I recall was of her accepting their captivity, and the rough ways of the man, and becoming part of “his” world, embracing the role she finds herself in. Oh, and their “captors” are never seen nor heard. Also, my recollection is that their place of captivity seemed reminiscent of the south pacific. Sand, water, tropical trees (versus desert, temperate rainforest, etc)

Comment: And their captors are never identified, I don’t recall. Seemed human, but could have been written to allow for them to be non-human.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly Isaac Asimov's "The Ugly Little Boy" (1958). The primitive guy is a child, not a man (a Neanderthal, to be precise). Otherwise, everything fits. The story was later expanded into a novel by Robert Silverberg (see cover below).

Wikipedia has [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ugly_Little_Boy), including this summary (ending not included here):

> A Neanderthal child is brought to the present day as a result of time travel experiments by Stasis Inc, a research organization. He cannot be removed from his immediate area because of the vast energy loss and time paradoxes that would result, and is kept in the present by way of a Stasis module. In order to care for the boy the organization hires Edith Fellowes, a children's nurse.
> Initially repelled by the boy's appearance, Edith soon begins to regard him as her own child, learning to love him and realizing that he is far more intelligent than she first imagined. She dubs him 'Timmie' and attempts to ensure that he has the best possible childhood despite his circumstance. She is enraged when the newspapers refer to him as an "ape-boy." Edith's love for Timmie brings her into conflict with her employer, for whom he is more of an experimental animal than a human being.

[image]

Comment: The OP says the woman was "also captured".

Comment: @user14111 Indeed, the OP's question differs from "The Ugly Little Boy" on that point. But that may be a **false memory**, related to the fact that the nurse eventually enters in conflict with her employer, which could be remembered as her being in that dome against her will from the start. The fact the OP asks about a man, not a child, is more problematic. He speaks of "bonding", which is true but a woman bonding to a child as if he was **her child** can hardly be remembered as a woman bonding to a man.

Comment: There are certainly false memories, and "The Ugly Little Boy" matches the description better than any other story I can think of at the moment. However, I think discrepancies between question and answer should be pointed out, so as not to mislead future users.

Comment: The storyline of The Ugly Little Big certainly fits nicely. However, in the story I recall, the woman and man eventually mate. Her sensibilities are at first shaken by the “forwardness”’of the man. But, while she feels the affront, she realizes he is gentle if forceful, and she eventually embraces being his mate, his woman and partner

Comment: I thought the story may have been among those in a 1974 compilation entitled Political Science Fiction: an Introductory Reader. Looked at the included story titles, but none seemed correct. Ordered a copy of the book to see directly.

Comment: By the way, all of you—and this site—are Remarkable. Been stewing over this for two decades. Read the story in 1984. I’m grateful for your help, and your knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: @Ketch You've added some story details in comments that you left out of your original question. Please edit your question to include these and **anything** else you can recall about the story. We try, but we need all the help we can get, and you nrver know what will jog someone's memory.

Comment: Will do. Excellent point.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this could be 1974's "The Fall of Colossus" (Book 2 of the Colossus trilogy) by D. F. Jones.

[image]

The Super Computer Colossus has complete control of the world (which it gained in the first book which was also made into a movie: Colossus: The Forbin Project https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064177/ )

EDIT: *I believe the Colossus Computer had built a replacement for itself and the new computer has taken over and Colossus has been shutdown in this book. So all references to Colossus actually refer to the new computer. (I cant recall if Colossus uploaded itself into the new computer, or let the new one take over.)*

One of the sub plots of the 2nd book is the computer discovers that Forbin's wife has been working with its enemies.

> A man who is rough, primitive in behavior, is captured, and placed within a "habitation" dome, along with a much more sophisticated woman

Colossus imprisons her on a remote island(?) or zoo type artificial nature enclosure(?), [I don't remember which, but do know they were the only ones there and it was well monitored with cameras] with a primitive island native.  Pretty sure the native did not speak English so they could not communicate.

She is does not know how to survive in the primitive environment, while the native is right at home, so she is dependent on him. However between survival tasks, (building shelter, gathering food/water/firewood etc.) The native also repeatedly satisfies his sexual "needs" with Forbin's wife.

> so that their behavior may be studied by psychologists

Colossus monitors the enclosure to learn more about human emotions. While also showing the videos to Forbin and studying his reactions.

> She finds his behavior abhorrent, repugnant, but eventually finds comfort in his simplicity, and bonds with him.

Initially, she is definitely unwilling to satisfy his "needs" and unable to stop him, but after a few months she is willing (and even eager?) to participate.

Comment: Maybe, but the OP says it was a short story in a collection.

Comment: @user14111 true, but Many of the plot points do match very closely. Unfortunately I dont have access to a copy now so cant add more detail than what I vaguely remember and some info from wikipedia.